# How To Handle Duedate with value in startDate using NgDatePicker Angular

Tags: angular

I try to determine the minDate of the dueDate on the Angular ngDatePicker based on the selected startDate.

For example I choose startDate: 16 May 2019, so I want the date before the startDate date on the dueDate to be disabled, according to the one selected on startDate.

I have tried using [(ngModel) to get the value from startDate so that it can be used as minDate in dueDate, but it can't.

Example Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <div class="input-group ml-3">
                <input class="col-sm-6 form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="logInDF"
                    formControlName="loginDateFrom" ngbDatepicker #logInDF="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="loginDateFrom">
                <div class="input-group-append" (click)="logInDF.toggle()">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLastName">To</label>
            <div class="input-group ml-3">
                <input class="col-sm-6  form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="logInDT"
                    formControlName="loginDateTo" ngbDatepicker #logInDT="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="loginDateFrom">
                <div class="input-group-append" (click)="logInDT.toggle()">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get MinDate from dueDate based on the value that is on StartDate?

Comment: You shouldn't mix reactive forms with ngmodel. Can you try removing it? Also, can I see the parent FormGroup for `loginDateFrom ` and `loginDateTo `?

Comment: parent group name is `formGroup`

Comment: Alright, I think I have solved your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reactive forms, I would recommend you to remove `ngModel` to prevent any confusion between the data flow (template driven vs reactive forms).

Then, on the ngBootstrap datepicker with the `formControlName` of `loginDateFrom`, bind the `(dateSelect)` event with a custom method `onSelect()`, which will be fired whenever. the user selects a date on the datepicker.

In addition, on the ngBootstrap datepicker with the `formControlName` of `loginDateTo`, you'll have to set the input bindings on `[minDate]` to the value of `loginDateTo`, which is `formGroup.value.loginDateTo`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-right form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="from">From</label>
      <div class="input-group ml-3">
        <input class="col-sm-6 form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="logInDF" formControlName="loginDateFrom" ngbDatepicker #logInDF="ngbDatepicker" (select)="onSelect($event)">
        <div class="input-group-append" (click)="logInDF.toggle()">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-left form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputLastName">To</label>
      <div class="input-group ml-3">
        <input class="col-sm-6  form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="logInDT" formControlName="loginDateTo" ngbDatepicker #logInDT="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="loginDateFrom">
        <div class="input-group-append" (click)="logInDT.toggle()">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, on your component.ts, we define the `onSelect()` method, we update the `loginDateTo` FormControl with the values from `loginDateFrom` by using [patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value).

```
onSelect(event) {
  //console.log(event);
  this.formGroup.patchValue({
    loginDateTo: event
  })
}
```

This will bind the right `[minDate]` value for `loginDateTo`'s, based on what is chosen on the first DatePicker.

I have created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znp6w7?file=app/datepicker-basic.ts) which replicates the desired behaviour above.

Comment: Thank you in advance. I really appreciate your help.